# how to list all the constraints for a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo db collection called `students` and when I tried to insert a record, I got an about duplicate `studentNumber`.

I want to run a command to show me all the constraints.  I tried `db.getCollectionInfos()` and this is all it told me about the students collection

```
        {
                "name" : "students",
                "type" : "collection",
                "options" : {

                },
                "info" : {
                        "readOnly" : false,
                        "uuid" : UUID("70f19e72-bca2-4c86-aa2a-174cfa422d11")
                },
                "idIndex" : {
                        "v" : 2,
                        "key" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "name" : "_id_"
                }
        },
```

There's no mention that `studentNumber` is a unique field.  Is there another command that I can run to list all the constraints on the `students` collection?

Comment: Are you seeing this in robo3T or a shell or compass? Compass might give you more details.

Comment: Did you check the indexes?